# how to find the target file's full(absolute path) of the symbolic link or soft link in python

Tags: python, linux, absolute-path, symlink

when i give 
ls -l /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf

```
lrwxrwxrwx <snip> /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf -> ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf
```

so for a symbolic link or soft link, how to find the target file's full(absolute path) in python,

If i use

`os.readlink('/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf')`

it outputs

`../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf`

but i need the absolute path not the relative path, so my desired output must be,

`/etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf`

how to replace the `..` with the actual full path of the parent directory of the symbolic link or soft link file.

Comment: `os.readlink` should work on ubuntu/windows, python 3.5. Just tested it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49590179/4752883

Answer (score 150):

```
os.path.realpath(path)
```

[os.path.realpath](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) returns the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any symbolic links encountered in the path.

Comment: os.path.realpath doesn't eliminate symbolic links in Python 3.2 under Windows 7.  (A bug?)

Comment: Hmmm... I see that this has been an open bug for 1.5 years:
http://bugs.python.org/issue9949

Comment: Yup getting this same problem, 3 years later :c

Comment: in Python3, if you're using a `Path` object, you can do the same thing by doing `path.resolve()`

Comment: If `C:\\Users\\PP` is a symlink to another directory, in Windows 10 using python 3.5, `os.path.realpath("C:\\Users\PP")`basically returns the symlink path, not the real path.

Comment: The Windows issue is fixed in Python 3.8: "Changed in version 3.8: Symbolic links and junctions are now resolved on Windows."

Comment: Note that this depends on your current directory. Docs [say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) "On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`".

Comment: This assumes that your working directory is at the file with the symlink

Comment: os.path.realpath  and ls -l have different results on mount driver

Answer (score 18):

As unutbu says, `os.path.realpath(path)` should be the right answer, returning the canonical path of the specified filename, resolving any symbolic links to their targets.  But it's broken under Windows.

I've created a patch for Python 3.2 to fix this bug, and uploaded it to:

http://bugs.python.org/issue9949

It fixes the `realpath()` function in `Python32\Lib\ntpath.py`

I've also put it on my server, here:

http://www.burtonsys.com/ntpath_fix_issue9949.zip

Unfortunately, the bug is present in Python 2.x, too, and I know of no fix for it there.

Comment: os.path.realpath  and ls -l have different results on mount driver

Answer (score 12):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath

also `joinpath()` and `normpath()`, depending on whether you're in the current working directory, or you're working with things elsewhere. `normpath()` might be more direct for you.

Specifically:

```
os.path.normpath( 
  os.path.join( 
    os.path.dirname( '/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf' ), 
    os.readlink('/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf') 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Be warned though: should you pass a path which is not a symlink to readlink it will get angry and give the following exception:
`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'your-path'`

Answer (score 11):

I recommend using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library for filesystem operations.

```
import pathlib

x = pathlib.Path('lol/lol/path')
x.resolve()
```

**Documentation** for `Path.resolve(strict=False)`: make the path absolute, resolving any symlinks. A new path object is returned.

Answer (score 1):

On windows 10, python 3.5, `os.readlink("C:\\Users\PP")` where "C:\Users\PP" is a symbolic link (not a junction link) works.

It returns the absolute path to the directory.

This works on Ubuntu 16.04, python 3.5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.readlink) says to use `os.path.join()`:

> The result may be either an absolute or relative pathname; if it is relative, it may be converted to an absolute pathname using `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), result)`.

Comment: `os.path.abspath` ?

Comment: Not needed, @dmitry_romanov. If you just called `os.path.abspath(result)`, it wouldn't know where the path should start. That's why you need to pass in `path`. If `result` is already an absolute path, then `join` is smart. From the docs: "If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component."